# Swift - Program to print and repeat message based on counter

Tags: swift

I have a work related learning course and struck with a hands-on question on Swift programming - **Control Transfer Statements** like break, continue, fallthrough, return, & throw.

**Write a function named `printMessage` that takes two parameters - a `string` message and an integer count. The `message` should print and repeat the message as specified in the `count` parameter.**

**Message:"`Hello , How are You`"**

**For instance take `Count` as 8**

**This should print Message:"`Hello , How are You`" 8 times consecutively.**

So far I got the below code working fine on Xcode, should use control transfer  Statements, so tried this. But some extra eyes/other best practice way would help. As I am stuck with this hands-on and it is stopping me to complete the course. The way its designed is it gets input on the text box on the web page and runs the code on the coding area and gets output, if it matches the expected output, it let you submit, but that does not means I am successful as it tests the code with their answer key and my code don't match the answer key and I am failing. Please help

```
func printMessage(message: String, count: Int){
    for i in 0...count{
        if( i == count){
            break;
        } else {
            print(message);
            continue;
        }
    }
}
let message: String = readLine()!;
let c = readLine();
let count: Int = Int(c!)!;
printMessage(message: message, count: count);
```

Comment: Why do you need to check for `i == count` **inside** the loop, the loop will already be doing this.  Since you're starting at `0`, you really should be looping to `count - 1` ... or start the loop at `1`. Either `for i in 0..<count{` or `for i in 1...count{`.  And Swift doesn't need `;` at the end of the lines ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I use the if case, so that I can use the conditional statement in the code, I dont find other ways to include conditional statements in the funtion :(

Comment: Well, technically, the `for-loop` is a conditional statement, but I might be misunderstanding your requirement

Comment: Sorry, Its should be control transfer statements like break-statement­, continue-statement­, fallthrough-statement­, return-statement­ & throw-statement­. I will edit the question @MadProgrammer

Comment: Why did you delete [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53253000/swift-program-to-print-and-repeat-message-based-on-counter) and post it again? All the help you received on that other one is now lost. Don't do that. Edit as needed is much better.

Comment: @rmaddy There was an answer for it, but the answer disappeared, so thought there was some error with the question posting, so posted again. Apologies.

Comment: @vikrammohan Like `@MadProgrammer` said, you shouldn't have that `if` within the loop. Maybe you have to use an `if` to check if count is **more than or equal to `0`** (outside the `for` loop), or if not, tell the user that they entered an incorrect number.

Comment: @George_E this is actually a coding Hands-on test, so I dont have other options than using `if` within the loop to use the `break` statement. I want help with using the Control Transfer statements in the function, don't know how to achieve it, can you help?

Comment: An option is that you could use a `while` loop, and use and when a variable you increment is equal to the `count` parameter value, you could `break` out the loop.

Comment: @George_E let me try `while` and submit the answer. Hope it works, will let you know, Thanks!

Comment: @George_E nope, the `while` loop with break and continue failed me as well.

Comment: @vikrammohan Add the code to your question for the `while` that you tried.

Comment: @George_E This is what I tried `func printMessage(message: String, count: Int){`
`    var i : Int = 0`
   ` while i <= count {`
        `if(i == count){`
         `   break
        `} else {`
            `print(message)`
           ` i += 1`
            `continue`
       ` }`
    `}`
`}`
`let message: String = readLine()!`
`let c = readLine()`
`let count: Int = Int(c!)!`
`printMessage(message: message, count: count)`

Comment: The course seems to be extremely theoretical. In practice any of the control statements makes the code pretty cumbersome 

Comment: @vadian yeah, it’s hard to get successful result, if the code checks line by line for correct code!

Comment: vikram , I also stucked at this question did you solve that question? comment here if you are recieved any ticket solution or any type of solution of this question.

Comment: @HarshBhut It looks like they changed the question now, its remove duplicate and sort array of Int with a function that returns an array. check it...I completed the course now

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code works as it is meant to, in a `while loop` and also incorporates the **Control Transfer Statements**, like you asked:

```
func printMessage(message: String, count: Int) {
    var i: Int = 0
    while true {
        if i < count {
            print(message)
            i += 1
        } else { break }
    }
}


let message: String = "Hello!"
let count: Int = 3
printMessage(message: message, count: count)
```

If there are any more specifications, let me know. Also, it would be helpful to have a link to the lesson/tutorial. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @vikrammohan I can't find the test. This is what I got to when I logged in: https://imgur.com/a/IQyFZ2R

Comment: Interesting, I was hoping you wont have access to it.

Comment: @vikrammohan The link also took me to your challenge (couldn't retake it). Also, it had an email which was `@tcs`, was that yours? 

Comment: @vikrammohan Lol. No problem  Do you still need help with anything?

Comment: Yeah, I still have not completed this test course :(

Comment: @vikrammohan How can I actually access it then?

Comment: I dont think you can access it unless you are part of tcs.

Comment: @vikrammohan I can probably sign in with the account you linked :p

Comment: :D That sounds tempting, but no, I dont want to get into trouble for this silly internal test course.

Comment: @vikrammohan Yeah of course not  I can't do anything then, I'm afraid. Surely there's a "show me the answer" option?

Comment: No, there is no such thing...when we submit the answer, it gets the desire output but on submission, it says I failed. I even tried looking into the source cant find how to get the correct answer.

Comment: @vikrammohan I guess you'll have to ask someone in your team ‍♂️ I can't help

Comment: Yeah, I even raised a incident for this, no one responded. But Thanks for your time!

Comment: @vikrammohan np :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with for loop:

```
func PrintMessage (message: String, count: Int) {
    for _ in 0..<count {
        print(message)
    }
}

let message = readLine()
let count = Int(readLine()!)

PrintMessage(message: message!, count: count!);
```

Comment: no I need to somehow incorporate the control transfer statements into the function printMessage

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, Hope this will help you :)

```
func printMessage(message: String, count: Int) {

    var localCount = 1

    while localCount <= count {

        print(message)

        localCount = localCount + 1
    }
}

printMessage(message: "Hello", count: 8)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func demoRepeat(string:String,counts:Int) -> (String,Int)
{
    var countss = ""
    for _ in 0...counts
    {
        print(string)
    }
return ("\(countss)",1)
}
demoRepeat(string: "hello", counts: 2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As your answer is currently written, is it unclear exactly what your code does. Please edit your answer to include some explaination of your code. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).